# cutting content from returned array with php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am trying to cut results out of the RBL data it pulls back.

Here is the code.

```
<?
$ips = file("list.inc");
foreach($ips as $ip)
{
$rblurl = 'http://rbl-check.org/rbl_api.php?ipaddress=' . trim($ip);
$boom = fopen($rblurl, "r");
$rbl = stream_get_contents($boom);
echo "</br>";
$data = explode(";",$rbl);
print "<pre>";
print_r($data[0]);
print "</pre>";
echo "</br>";
//fclose($boom);
}
?>
```

This is the result.

```
emailbasura;bl.emailbasura.org;nowebsite;notlisted
Sorbs;zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net;nowebsite;notlisted
msrbl;combined.rbl.msrbl.net;nowebsite;notlisted
nixspam;ix.dnsbl.manitu.net;nowebsite;notlisted
Spamcop;bl.spamcop.net;nowebsite;notlisted
```

I am trying to cut the first part and the last part so it only displays this.

```
emailbasura notlisted
Sorbs notlisted
msrbl notlisted
nixspam notlisted
Spamcop notlisted
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Maybe preg_grep() help to you?

Comment: Or read it as CSV with semicolons being the delimiter, see `str_getcsv()`. You forgot to break up the lines beforehand, btw.

Comment: How can the result contain `;` when you just have exploded on `;`? I would expect the result to be just `emailbasura`. And you need to do it line-by-line of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to explode the data by the line breaks not just the delimeter:

```
$data = explode("\n",$rbl);
```

once you've done that you just echo out the data:

```
foreach($data as $item) {
  $item = explode(';',$item);
  echo $item[0].' '.$item[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $d) 
{
  $arr_data = explode(';',$d);
  $first_data = $arr_data[0];
  $last_data =  $arr_data[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change here

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($data[0]);
print "</pre>"
```

as

```
print "<pre>";
$spl = split(';', $data[0]);
echo $spl[0] . $spl[3];
print "<pre>";
```